# what's the "peer" and two "address:port" from "ss -l" command mean

Tags: linux

When I use "ss-l" command to display all open network ports in centos7, the output has two "address:port" fields.

Like this

[image]

Is this for local address and foreign address? And what's the "peer" mean.

I am confused on it. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the two "Address:Port" columns are for the IP address and port being used locally and by the other end of the connection.

"Peer" is a common term used for the machine on the other end of a network connection because, historically, all servers on the internet were originally considered to be equal peers rather than divided into "client machines" and "server machines".

In the output of `ss -l`, the peer is always listed as `*` (used as a wildcard) because the `-l` option tells it to show only ports which are listening for new connections, not those which have connections established.  If you run `ss` without `-l`, you should get some `Peer Address:Port` entries such as `1.2.3.4:https`, showing that you have an active https connection to a peer with IP address 1.2.3.4.

Comment: There are a bunch of entries with Peer Address `0.0.0.0:*`, which I'm guessing means the process is bound to the Local Address but there is no active connection to it.  Is this correct?

Comment: @theferrit32 - Close. `0.0.0.0` generally means _all_ local addresses. So, if the local machine has ipv4 address `5.6.7.8`, `0.0.0.0` would be bound to `5.6.7.8` _and_ `127.0.0.1` _and_ `::1` (if ipv6 is active) _and_ any other addresses the machine might have.

Comment: In the case of `0.0.0.0` as the local address bound to, that makes sense to me. But here `ss` shows `0.0.0.0:*` as the peer address (netstat does as well), even when the local address is `127.0.0.1`, so it's impossible to reach from a peer in all interfaces, only the local loopback interface. For example if I bind to a local port with `nc -l 127.0.0.1 9999` but nothing connects to it, `ss -lt` shows that local address having a peer address of `0.0.0.0:*`, which is confusing to me in the case when the local address is on a loopback interface.